# What happens to Zygarde cells if I trade Zygarde away?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon, pokemon-seventh-generation

One of those random questions that pops into your head.

If I have a 10% Forme Zygarde and I trade it away to another game, does that mean the cells that make it up are lost and I am unable to assemble 100% Zygarde?

On the flip side, if I receive a Zygarde in a trade, can I break that down into cells?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, if you trade away a Zygarde of any %, you will lose however many cells it took to construct it. See [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemon/comments/5e3uzs/psa_dont_trade_your_zygarde_forms/):

> Creating a zygarde will reduce the current percentage in your zygarde box. Trading this will not refund any cells, and you are unable to re-acquire them.
>
> I wonder traded 2 10% forms, and have lost that 20%.

---

On the flip side, you *are* able to have more than 100 Zygarde cells. From [this discussion](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/187276-pokemon-sun/74597441) about what happens if you break down a Zygarde you received in a trade:

> Okay, I tested it out. It doesn't register you as having more than X/100 Zygarde, but the game acts like you do anyway. My Zygarde now has the Power Construct ability.